# Html strips out white spaces.

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

This is a bit silly. I use Rails for my web app. It acquires data from the database using statements like

```
<div class="show-content"> <%= @page.content %> </div>
```

A sample html output of the same.

```
<div class="show-content">
Migrations are a convenient way for you to alter your database in a structured and organized manner.

Active Record tracks which migrations have already been run so all you have to do is update your source and run rake db:migrate. 

Migrations also allow you to describe these transformations using Ruby. 
</div>
```

As you can see, they consist of 3 paragraphs. But when they get displayed, the newlines(whitespaces) get stripped, which is not what I want. Should I create a helper or is there an inbuilt function to do that?

Comment: if the spacing is important, wrap the text you fetch from the db in <pre> tags so whitespace is honored.

Comment: Browsers displaying HTML are supposed to gobble whitespace, reducing it to a single space; That's just how they work. You, as the programmer are supposed to know that and explicitly tell the browser how to break paragraphs using some sort of markup, whether it's a `<p>`, `<br>`, `<div>`, or some other tag.

Comment: @theTinMan I think you got me wrong there. page.content can store any number of paragraphs and that includes white spaces. I have no explicit way of separating those paragraphs and adding a '<p>' tag each paragraph using html. I would have had to use  Rails at some point. As Mike pointed out, I could use <pre> but that didn't seem like the Rails way of doing it. dKen had the perfect solution for it.

Comment: `I have no explicit way of separating those paragraphs and adding a '<p>' tag each paragraph using html.` It's easy to split the text into paragraphs. `'<p>' + page.content.gsub(/\n\n+/, '</p><p>').gsub(/\n/, '<br/>') + '</p>'` is a starting point. You might as well use `simple_format` since it's there, but the reformatting is easy, and why you need to do it is the basis of using HTML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `simple_format()` which transforms the input using HTML rules. [TextHelper#simple_format documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format)

Comment: Thanks. That was a quick fix :)

Answer (score 1):

you are going to probably have to do one of two things.

process the content on the server so each 'line' gets wrapped in `<p>` tags and style them as needed

or

change your template to something like this:

```
<div class='show-content'>
    <pre><%= @page.content %></pre>
</div>
```